# Counting overlapping events based on date

Tags: excel

Background info - For a trading backtesting calculation sheet - I'm trying to determine how many OPEN positions occur or overlap based on start and end dates, but it needs to be dynamic, i.e. the entire result range must recalculate when a new line is added and sorted by OPEN date.

The OPEN dates are located in range D6:D1006, and their accompanying CLOSE dates are in F6:F1006 and the calculated result will be displayed in S6:S1006.

An example (Shown by adding more line items numbers, i.e. ignore the sheet row numbers in this example):

[image]

When Line 1 is added, the result is obviously 1 since there is only 1 date range.

When Line 2 is added, the dates overlap with Line 1's dates, so both line's result becomes 2, and so forth.

I'm not sure if an array formula is needed in range S6:S1006, or how to go about doing this without using VBA (Though that's not off the table) or extensive helping columns/rows to manipulate the data to get the required result. I'm expecting overlaps results of about 10 - 20 or so.

If it helps, columns C, D, E, F, and G are filled by hand, and columns H to R (and S if this works) have formulas that take whatever is entered in C, D, E, F, and G, and runs the calculation no matter how the data is sorted - though it's normally by OPEN date - oldest to newest.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I think you should be able to achieve your desired outcome with COUNTIFS.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842  (In fact, their example at the bottom demonstrates comparison of a date cell value with a range of date cells).  Have a crack and see how you go, then perhaps add to your question with your attempted formula if you think it's not quite right

Comment: For versions supporting Dynamic Arrays: `=SUM((@D:D<=F:F)*(@F:F>=D:D))`.  Earlier versions (for cell `S6`) `=SUM((D6<=F:F)*(F6>=D:D))`. Or use a table and structured references `=SUM(([@Open]<=[Close])*([@Close]>=[Open]))`